# Using a Date to change a Button's text

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker

I have the following situation:
I have a Dialog. Within this dialog, which is a Fragment, I have a Button. This Button calls a DatePickDialog (DatePickFragment). If I set the date, the method

```
onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day)
```

is called, if I am correct. (If not, please tell me!). Now I want to change the Text of the Button to the Date. I already have a method that transforms the date to a String. But I cannot figure out how I get from the onDateSet method to the Button in the xml file...
I cannot use findViewById. I thought I could use the view (DatePicker) but I do not know how...

The Java File for the DatePicker is in a seperate package (tools).It would be perfect to reuse this method if it is needed somewhere else. But that is not so important to me at the moment.

Some more code:
DatePickerFragment.java

```
package com.domain.app.tools;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener
{
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day)
    {
        //Here I am stuck
        dateToString(year, month, day);
    }

    public String dateToString(int year, int month, int day)
    {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append(day + "." + month + "." + year);

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

dialog_create.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id = "@+id/dialog_create"
    android:layout_width = "match_parent"
    android:layout_height = "match_parent"
    android:background="@color/create_bg_1"
    tools:context = ".CreateDialogFragment"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id = "@+id/dialog_create_name"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "@dimen/textFieldHight"
        android:text = "@string/create_name"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        />


    <Button
        android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
        android:layout_height = "@dimen/textFieldHight"
        android:ems = "6"
        android:text = "@string/date"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id = "@+id/create_date_button"
        android:onClick = "pickDate"
        android:layout_below = "@id/dialog_create_name"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java - Partially

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements HomeFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener
{
    CreateDialogFragment createDialogFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        homeFragment = new HomeFragment();

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.mainFrame, homeFragment).commit();
        findViewById(R.id.bottomButton_home).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_home);
    }



    public void openCreate(View view)
    {
        createDialogFragment = new CreateDialogFragment();
        createDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, "TEST");

        updateSelectedButton(3);
    }




    public void pickDate(View v)
    {
        DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
        datePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.pickDate)));

        ((EditText) v).setText();//Here I am stuck
    }
[...]
}
```

Comment: can your paste more of you code ?

Comment: I edited the question so there are now the relevant code samples...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'm guessing the button you're trying to change the text of, lives in your MainActivity.

You have to set an interface my friend.

I think, not sure, you can override the onAttach method in your `DatePickerFragment` and treat your parameter activity as an interface.

Then, call a method in that interface to do the button text change.

It would be roughly something like:

```
//You create a new interface
public interface MyInterface {
  public void changeTheButton(/*The parameters you need to send form the fragment to the activity*/);
}
```

Then in your fragment:

```
//In your DatePickerFragment
MyInterface i;

@Override
public void onAttach (Activity theParentActivity) {
  i = (MyInterface) theParentActivity;
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day)
{
  //Here you call the interface
  i.changeTheButton(/* you send the neccesary info from your date to your activity */);
  dateToString(year, month, day);
}
```

And finally in your Activity

```
//This is in your MainActivity, note you're imlementing the new MyInterface interface
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements HomeFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener, MyInterface {
  ...
  @Override
  public void changeTheButton(/*The parameters you need to send form the fragment to the a
  Activity*/){
    //This is where you receive the parameters from fragment, and change the button text as you need.
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

## EDIT

Further explanation as requested:

@JRsz Think of an interface as the best way to communicate way up. You can easily now send messages from the `Activity` to the `Fragment` (way down) because `Activity` is the parent of the `Fragment`, so inside the `Activity` you have access to the `Fragment` instance.

On the other hand, from the `Fragment` to the `Activity` (way up) is a bit different because you don't have access to the `Activity` instance. That's why you make use of the `OnAttach` method in the fragment, to obtain access to the `Activity` instance.

You could save the instance in a reference inside your fragment and then call `theParentActivity.theMethodImLookingFor(theParameters);` and it would work, but it's not recommended due to the fact that the `Fragment` could be attached to multiple activities, and you wouldn't be sure the parent activity has the method you're looking for... and that's when the interface takes place!

The interface is the right way to make sure the method you're looking for, is implemented in the `Activity` you're referring to. An interface is nothing more but a list of methods you want to implement in a class, and call from another.

So steps are:
1. Create the interface (a separate file)
2. Implement the interface in your `Activity` (that forces you to Override the methods you put in the interfaces, in your `MainActivity`)
3. Override the `onAttach` method in your `Fragment`, and cast the `Activity` that comes in parameter, as an interface. (Save the interface instance globally in your fragment)
4. Use the interface in the fragment once you make the `OnDate` change, sending the parameters you need. (That will call the method in your activity).

Let me know if it was clear, and if it worked to you.

Comment: I am still dealig with this problem, but I do not understand your answer completly. Maybe I just need some more time, but could you explain, how exactly thhe sending and receiving via the interface works? I do not know enough about interfaces to entirely understand your code...

Comment: ok, sending the date to the main activity works. That is basically what I wanted. I will upvote your answer and so on, but there is still one bug: when I try too set the Text, it crashes. The text is a String and the Button is in a dialog, I think this is causing the problem. I get a Nullpointer exception....
This is the method: http://pastebin.com/XGwEKuyK

Comment: If the Button you're trying to set lives in your dialog, it's a whole different story, that's why I said in first place that I assumed the button lived in your Activity by looking at the xml you posted. If the Dialog with the Date is the same one with the button, you could use just a local method.

Answer (score 0):

do it this way : you need to decalare a Button as variable and use it in your methods

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements HomeFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener
{
    CreateDialogFragment createDialogFragment;
    Button btn = new Button();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        homeFragment = new HomeFragment();

        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.mainFrame, homeFragment).commit();
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bottomButton_home);
        btn..setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_home);
    }



    public void openCreate(View view)
    {
        createDialogFragment = new CreateDialogFragment();
        createDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, "TEST");

        updateSelectedButton(3);
    }




    public void pickDate(View v)
    {
        DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
        datePicker.show(getFragmentManager(), String.format(getResources().getString(R.string.pickDate)));

        btn.setText();//Here I am stuck
    }
[...]
}
```

Comment: if I am correct, this is what the compiler does. But how do I get the information about the picked date??

Comment: didn't get your question

Comment: If I pick a date an click OK on the datePickerPopUp the method onDatePicked is beeing called. So here is the date I have and I need to use. But how can I get it out of there? So back to the MainActivity, where I need it...